# AnyChart line chart displays x-axis non symmetrical

Tags: java, android, anychart

I'm using AnyChart for Android to display data by date.
Every Day one datapoint is created so the line chart could contain 1 to n ticks.
Currently with about 30 data entries every 5th date is displayed in the labels, which is fine.
But while the first label and the last label are displayed correctly, inbetween labels are not centered and look asymmetrical.

[image: AnyChartExample]

This behaviour can also be seen in the AnyChart [Docu](https://docs.anychart.com/Axes_and_Grids/Axis_Basics#labels)
Is there a way to spread out these labels symmetrically?

I've not configured anything for the x-axis so thats the basic layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct and expected behavior. In the Cartesian charts, names on the X-axis are referred to categories, not ticks. So, the category name is placed in the center of the category. But linear, logarithmic and dateTime scales place labels next to the ticks.